# How to consult value of field with ant-design useForm?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have this form which I would like to show or hide fields depending on the value of other field(s) that are fix (they never hide) but using `form.getFieldValue("some-field")` always return `undefined`.

Here is a minimal functional example that showcase the issue I have:

[image: Edit loving-almeida-tb1h2]

What am I doing wrong with antd and how can I achieve my use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By looking into the [official documentation](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-control-hooks), they have provided a way to use conditions inside `<Form.Item>`.

```
<Form.Item
  noStyle
  shouldUpdate={(prevValues, currentValues) => prevValues.gender !== currentValues.gender}
>
  {({ getFieldValue }) =>
    getFieldValue('gender') === 'other' ? (
      <Form.Item
        name="customizeGender"
        label="Customize Gender"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
    ) : null
  }
</Form.Item>
```

I have changed your example to work as expected. Please check.

[image: Edit blue-platform-06fji]

Comment: This works but my goodness this is terrible design on antd's part...

Comment: @andymccullough I agree with you. I wonder if there is any update on this without this ugly design.